# SQL Filter in Select Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is giving me this result

```
StoreID  BlockID DateOfEntry UPC            OnExit      
AA003    AAA416   29-09-13   6281100021049  Available   
AA003    AAA417   29-09-13   6281100021049  Low OOS-Trigger
```

`OnExit`  is calculated runtime  based on the formula (not seen). Now the only difference between the two values for the same store is there different `BlockID`

What I desire is something like this
If `Low OOS-Trigger` then display only that. If not then display `Available`.

**Desired Result** should appear something like this

```
StoreID  DateOfEntry UPC            OnExit      
AA003    29-09-13   6281100021049   Low OOS-Trigger
```

I have tried doing `Distinct` but still resulted in 2 rows. provide above. Any hints.

Query:

```
select * from dbv1.viewTable
where dateofentry='2013-09-29'
and storeid='AA003' and BlockID in ('AAA416','AAA417')
and [upc]  ='6281100021049'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below `ROW_NUMBER()` which is a ranking functions that generates sequential number. It partitions the records via `StoreID` and sorted it by the value of `OnExit` using `CASE` statement. This will only display 1 record for every `StoreID`.

```
SELECT  StoreID, BlockID, DateOfEntry, UPC, OnExit
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  StoreID, BlockID, DateOfEntry, UPC, OnExit,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreID, UPC 
                    ORDER BY CASE WHEN OnExit = 'Low OOS-Trigger' THEN 1
                                ELSE 0 END) rn
            FROM    dbv1.viewTable
            -- WHERE    dateofentry = '2013-09-29'
            --      AND storeid = 'AA003' 
            --      AND BlockID in ('AAA416','AAA417')
            --      AND [upc]  = '6281100021049'
        ) a
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26c02/3)

Comment: Sorry, If I wasn't clear. I want 1 record for every StoreID & Upccode. There combination on a particular date should result in one value

Comment: you just need to add `UPC` in `PARTITION BY` clause.